# Azure CloudQueue.addMessage() doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-queues, cloud-storage

I have this simple code:

```
      public void addMessage(string msg, string queueName)
    {
        CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(msg);
        try {
           CloudQueue queue = getQueue(queueName);
           bool exists = queue.Exists();
           queue.AddMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.ToString();
        }

    }

   public CloudQueue getQueue(string queueName)
             {
                CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
                CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);
                queue.CreateIfNotExists();
                return queue;
            }
```

The message is set correctly, the queue name is correct, the queue exists but after call `queue.AddMessage(message)` the queue is still empty and no Exception is thrown. How is possible? With Blob and Table everything works fine (insert, delete, etc). I really cannot explain this.

Comment: Can you please explain why do you say "queue is still empty"? How are you checking the existence of messages in the queue?

Comment: From Visual Studio (Server Explorer) and from Azure Storage Explorer. Moreover, I placed a breakpoint on Worker Role when pop (from the Queue) a message that is not null. The Debugger never reachs this breakpoint, another proof that anything is added in the queue.

Comment: I also noticed that you are eating any exceptions that occur in your `addMessage` method. Could it be possible that your code is throwing an exception but you never come to know about it?

Comment: I use Debug to see if some exception is thrown, and everything goes "fine", in the sense that the method ends correctly.

Comment: Hmmm....totally weird! Your code looks OK to me (it can be optimized but that's another thing). Can you try adding following two lines of code after `queue.AddMessage(message);`: `queue.FetchAttributes(); int? messagesCount = queue.ApproximateMessageCount;`. Please check the value of `messagesCount` variable. If the message is inserted properly, you should see a non-null, non-zero value there. Also it wouldn't hurt to check the queue contents in a different storage explorer.